# Find a maximum likelihood estimator in discrete uniform distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, uniform-distribution, censoring

$X$ is distributed as discrete uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,...C\}$ where $C$ is an integer higher than or equal to 4

$Pr(X=x)=p$ for $x ∈ \{1,2,\dotsc,\}$ which means $Cp=1$

$X$ is censored and we can only observe $Y=\min(x,4)$ IID with sample $\{_1, ... , _\}$

I want to find a maximum likelihood estimator for $p$ and this is how I was thinking:

Because only $Y$ is observable and $Y=\min(x,4)$, possible $Y$ values are 1,2,3,4.

One can observe $Pr(Y_i=1)$ with $p$ because $Pr(X=1)=p$ and 1 is smaller than 4. The same applies to $Y_i=2,3$.

When $x$ is higher than or equal to 4, we can only observe $Y_i=4$ due to $Y=\min(x,4)$. Thus, I thought $Pr(Y_i=4)= 1-3p$

To find a maximum likelihood estimator for $p$, I need to first come up with a probability mass function which I can use to find the likelihood function. This is where I am stuck.

I want to know whether I am right in approaching the given question or not.

Comment: You can express the likelihood as $L(p)=p^{n-r}(1-3p)^r$ where $r$ are the number of $y_i=4$ and $n-r$ are the remaining observations.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/562063/119261